# Overiding constant in C#

Tags: c#

I have such class in c#:

```
public class Foo 
{
    public static readonly int SIZE = 2;
    private int[] array;

    public Foo
    {
        array = new int[SIZE];
    }

}
```

and `Bar` class:

```
public class Bar : Foo
{
    public static readonly int SIZE = 4;

}
```

What I want to accopmlish is to create a Bar instance with array size taken from overrided `SIZE` value. How to do it properly?

Comment: You can set readonly arguments in the constructor, but probably not static readonly since it would need to be set in the static constructor which doesn't take arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it this way. You could use a virtual method:

```
public class Foo 
{
    protected virtual int GetSize(){return 2;};
    private int[] array;

    public Foo
    {
        array = new int[GetSize()];
    }
}
```

It's also possible to use reflection to look for a static field `SIZE`, but I don't recommend that.

Answer (score 2):

Your SIZE constant is static, and static fields aren't inherited - Foo.SIZE and Bar.SIZE are two different constants that have nothing to do with each other. That's why Foo's constructor call will always initialize with 2, not 4.

What you can do is create a `protected virtual void Initialize()` method in Foo that initializes the array with 2, and override it in Bar to initialize it with 4.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot inherit static fields; instead use the below:

```
public class Foo
{
    protected virtual int SIZE
    {
        get
        {
            return 2;
        }
    }

    private int[] array;

    public Foo()
    {
        array = new int[SIZE];
    }
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
    protected override int SIZE
    {
        get
        {
            return 4;
        }
    }
}
```

Virtual is like saying "This is the default value of the base class"; whilst Override changes the value on the class implementing "Foo".

Comment: -1 You can't put virtual and override on fields. Instead use properties or methods to return a value.

Comment: Fair cop, changed to use properties